# Can i use an other language instead of english for default django translation

Tags: django, translation

Can I use another language instead of english(say, french) for default django translation.

For example, instead for doing this:

```
messages.error(request, _('My message in english'))
```

I do this:

```
messages.error(request, _('Mon message en francais'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you could do that, and it would *mostly* work, but better would be to write them in English and then provide French translations (via the standard [i18n](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/) approach), and to set the project's [LANGUAGE_CODE](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#language-code) to 'fr' as well.

That way, your code will be more easily reusable in other languages, and - perhaps more usefully to you if you're not worried about that - you'll be able to *cleanly* use French/other language translations already available in any third-party apps you want to add to your site, else you'll be mixing what Django thinks is default English (but is French) and thinks is French (and is French)

Allez! ;o)